# Documents et institutions de référence de la langue

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, histoire, standard

Quels ont été et quels sont aujourd'hui les différents documents et institutions régissant la langue française ?

Il me vient évidemment en tête l'[Académie française](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise), ses immortels et son dictionnaire. Ce dictionnaire est-il aujourd'hui la (seule ?) référence de la langue ?
Dans l'article de Wikipédia, le paragraphe *[Imposer le standard](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#Imposer_le_standard)* semble noter que, malgré cette apparente référence, d'autres entités peuvent aussi modifier les règles du jeu. Quelles sont-elles et dans quel cadre agissent-elles ?

Enfin, on parle beaucoup du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française, mais qu'en est-il de la grammaire ? L'article en question note :

> Le même travail avait été entrepris pour établir la Grammaire de l'Académie dont la publication sera reportée d'année en année.

Y a-t-il un projet de « Grammaire de l'Académie française » ou un autre ouvrage (Grevisse ?) a-t-il pris cette place ? Où se situent aussi les ouvrages et sites souvent cités ici tels que *[Le bon usage](http://www.lebonusage.com/)*, le *[Trésor de la langue française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/)*, etc. ?

Comment: À chaque fois que tu ne laisses pas un espace entre tes paragraphes, la créature surnaturelle de ton choix tues un animal cute. Pense aux animaux cutes!

Comment: @Borror0 !! Quelle horreur ! Je ne savais pas que j'avais participé à un tel génocide. Crois bien que j'y regarderai maintenant à deux fois ;) Merci pour l'edit.

Comment: @Borror0 +1, mais vu qu'on parle français ici, on pourrait utiliser "mignon" plutôt, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour ce qui est des institutions de normalisation de la langue française, les principales, historiquement et encore aujourd'hui, sont l'**Académie française** et l'**Office québécois de la langue française**.

Cependant, des organismes dont ce n'est pas la vocation officielle y participent aussi de fait : éditeurs de dictionnaires, de grammaires, divers ministères (cités dans [le paragraphe en question](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise#Imposer_le_standard)).

Quant à l'usage courant, qui par définition n'est pas normalisé, toute personne parlant français participe aux variations de la langue.

S'agissant de la grammaire de l'Académie, je suis tombé sur [cet article](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article162). *Tl;dr* : Oui il y a eu deux éditions d'une grammaire de l'Académie, mais elles n'ont eu aucun succès et n'ont pas une grande valeur, à part peut-être pour apprendre l'humilité aux Immortels.

Enfin, les ouvrages de référence souvent cités, ici comme ailleurs, ont surtout l'autorité de l'usage et, pour le TLF en particulier, celui de la documentation. C'est parce que beaucoup de gens faisant autorité les utilisent depuis longtemps et les désignent comme des références qu'ils le sont devenus.

Note : le CNRTL n'est pas un ouvrage en soi, c'est plutôt une passerelle d'accès à plusieurs ouvrages faisant autorité.

Answer (score 3):

Le Bled est un ouvrage qui a probablement joué un grand rôle dans la normalisation de la langue française de part l'usage intensif qui en est fait dans les écoles primaires, et ce depuis l'époque de nos grands-mères.

Comment: Et le Bescherelle!

Answer (score 3):

Qu'on me pardonne de donner ici dans le coup de sang, fruit de mon expérience quotidienne comme correcteur.

L'Académie ne se définit elle-même que comme entérinant « l'usage » en matière de graphie des mots, et elle ne fait qu'évoquer des registres de langue périmés sans définir la grammaire. Elle cultive les exceptions et les incohérences tout au long d'un dictionnaire qui met un temps fou à se régénérer (voir Littré qui n'a cessé de dénoncer tout cela). Les dictionnaires de référence (*Larousse* et *Robert*) sont devenus des affaires commerciales qui fédèrent mal. Les différents grammairiens (Grevisse, Hanse, Thomas) sont souvent abscons et méconnus de l'immense majorité des locuteurs. La typographie est le parent pauvre malmené dans beaucoup d'ouvrages. La prononciation (orthoépie) n'a pas de vrai statut et est souvent un facteur arbitraire de ségrégation sociale.

In fine, la langue française est une divinité défendue par une série de zélotes qui tirent chacun de leur côté sans égard ni pour l'ensemble de la Francophonie (en pleine expansion) ni pour la moindre logique. Peu d'autres langues baignent dans une telle confusion au niveau des normes. Les récentes querelles autour des quelques rectifications de 1990 ou de l'écriture dite inclusive donnent une idée du niveau limité du débat. L'Assemblée nationale française vient d'ailleurs de demander la création d'une commission visant à définir de manière stable les principes régissant la langue française, qui figure rappelons-le dans la Constitution. Sinon, tout le monde va finir avec le correcteur Google comme unique viatique.