# Comment traduire « a cute animal » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Je voulais suggérer une traduction pour [le commentaire de Borror0](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/312/documents-et-institutions-de-reference-de-la-langue) pour « *a cute animal* », mais je dois bien dire qu'aucun mot adéquat ne me vient à l'esprit.

Pourtant, [ce ne sont pas les possibilités qui manquent](http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/vertalen.php?woord=cute&src=EN&des=FR), mais je trouve que même « un animal mignon » ou « un joli animal » ne rendent pas justice au mot « *cute* ».

Le plus convaincant, je trouve, serait « un adorable animal ».

Que peut-on dire d'autre ?

Comment: Je trouve que "mignon" donne bien le sens de "cute".

Comment: Dans le cas du commentaire en question, j'aurais traduit par "un petit animal".

Comment: Tiens, personne n'a encore proposé "un animal aigu"...

Comment: @Evpok D'accord avec toi, je viens de voir ton commentaire (avec 3 ans de retard, bref ^^). J'ai fait une réponse en ce sens, mais vu le délai j'imagine que je ne te coupe pas l'herbe sous le pied...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Mignon" est le mot le plus adapté pour traduire *cute*.

Par contre, autant cette expression est très utilisée en anglais, autant en français ça ne sonne pas du tout naturel et je ne vois aucun moyen de la traduire correctement.

Une alternative (un peu exagérée et ridicule) serait de dire "trop chou" pour *cute* (ça fait très adolescente excitée devant un chaton ou un hamster).

Comment: +1 pour mignon. *Cute* très (trop !) utilisé par ma cousine québécoise.

Comment: Haaa oui, "chou", c'est déjà plus ce que je cherchais. Et dans le genre, "mimi" ou "minouche".

Comment: Choupinou ! [ ](http://www.example.com/)

Comment: Je peux t'assurer que *mignon* est régulièrement utilisé par ma fille pour qualifier des animaux ;)

Comment: @Pierre: ce n'est pas tant l'adjectif qui me gêne, mais l'expression. « un animal mignon » ou « un mignon animal », ça sonne un peu surfait...

Comment: @Raphink: dans la bouche d'un adulte, très certainement

Comment: +1 pour mignon, +1 pour 'cute' omniprésent en québécois...

Comment: Sinon *adorable* devrait passer aussi

Answer (score 7):

Si *mignon* ne te convient pas (pas assez courant ?), alors ***chou*** me semble la plus proche alternative, pour le même coût en lettres et en syllabes. Comme envisage [ℝaphink](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/320/1514) sans être trop convaincu, moi je vois bien « *trop chou* » traduire « *so cute* ».

Autre possibilité pas encore mentionnée : ***à croquer***, qui traduit la même adoration, mais avec des vrais mots, quelque part.

Answer (score 7):

Il y aussi aussi *[trognon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trognon)*, qui peut être vu comme portemanteau de *trop* et *mignon*.

Answer (score 1):

Les propositions principales couvrent déjà bien le sujet, j'ajoute seulement une variante.

On peut utiliser le simple adjectif *petit*, parfait raccourci en *p'tit* (voire même *'tit*), pour donner immédiatement la connotation qu'on trouve dans l'anglais *cute*.

On a une foule d'exemples dans des expressions extrêmement courantes, notamment dans des contextes de langage enfantins, naïfs voire souvent aussi ironiques.

> Un **p'tit** lapin, des **p'tites** fleurs, les **p'tits** oiseaux *(difficile à lire sans entendre un ton ironique, certains crieront à la niaiserie)*
>
> Un lapin, des fleurs, les oiseaux *(la différence de ton est très sensible, ici on est neutre, descriptif, on pourrait lire cette énumération dans un article de journal)*

Comment: Je le racourcirais même en « 'tit ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui tu as raison je l'ai ajouté, et les 3 versions (*petit p'tit 'tit*) sont utilisées, selon les contextes.