# Pourquoi « comment vous appelez-vous », et pas « quel est votre nom » comme en anglais ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, salutations, comparaison-de-langues

We know that when French people want to know someone's name, ask “*Comment vous appelez-vous ?*”. However this literally means “How do you call yourself?”. Why they don't use something like “*quel est votre nom*” which can be mapped to English translation of “what's your name”?

I mean, in many languages, people ask “what is your name”, not “how do you call yourself”. Does it have any socio-historical background? Why is it so special?

---

Pour demander le nom de quelqu'un, la question usuelle en français est « Comment vous appelez-vous ? », ce qui en anglais voudrait littéralement dire « *How do you call yourself?* ». Pourquoi le français n'emploie-t-il pas de tournures du type « Quel est votre nom ? », similaires à l'anglais « *What is your name?* » ?

Dans la plupart des langues, l'équivalent est du type « *What is your name* », et pas « *How do you call yourself?* ». Cet usage a-t-il des raisons socio-historiques ? Pourquoi est-il si particulier ?

Comment: *Quel est votre nom?* is correct too, albeit a little more informal. A more formal one would be *À qui ai-je l'honneur?*.

Comment: The "what's your name?" construction is not native to English - a Germanic language; it is the result of the original Celtic substrate influence.  This very question [has already been asked and answered from the English point of view in EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28766/how-did-english-get-the-what-is-your-name-construction).

Comment: Voting to close the question since it's unfounded : "Quel est votre nom?" IS used. There is just more than one way to ask for a name in french.

Comment: "Quel est votre nom **s'il vous plait**?" pourrait passer si par exemple l'on remplit un formulaire à ta place. La version sans la locution de politesse te ferait passer pour un rustre.

Comment: I can't answer, (Spanish does the same thing) but I wanted to say that I watched a French film (originally French- made my the French) where a woman said "Quel est votre nom" when asking for a name. The English dub had her say "Do you have a name" though.

Comment: Because it's French, and not English..

Comment: Il  n'y a aucune vraie réponse à cette question, je suis assez déçue. La question est difficile, certes!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**French version:** J'ai cherché pendant longtemps et à beaucoup d'endroits, mais je n'ai  rien trouvé qui pourrait expliquer l'histoire de l'usage de cette expression. Je pense qu'il n'y a peut-être pas de réponse claire et nette sur le net. (Si je trouve une information, je l'ajouterai.)

Mais il n'est pas tout à fait vrai que beaucoup de langues utilisent la construction "what's your name" et que le français est une exception. Il y a des langues qui utilisent l'autre forme. Pour n'en citer que quelques-unes:

<sup>If you find mistakes, feel free to correct. :)</sup>

---

**English version:** I've searched for a while and in many ways, but I couldn't find anything that could answer your question about the socio-historical background behind this usage. And I'm starting to think there really isn't some definite answer available on the net to this question. (If something comes up, I'll make sure to edit the answer.)

But it's not actually true that many languages use the "what's your name" kind of expression and French is an exception or that this is "special". There are also other languages who don't ask that using that structure. Just to name a few:

> I included the literal, not conceptual, translation as you asked:
>
> - Come ti chiami? - (*How do you call yourself?*) - Italian
> - ¿Cómo te llamas? - (*How do you call yourself?*) - Spanish
> - Wie heißt du? - (*How are you called?*) - German
> - Как тебя зовут? - (*How do they call you?*) - Russian
> - Vad heter du? - (*How are you called?*) - Swedish
>
> <sup>It's also true that such structures can also mean "to have the name", such as the italian one and perhaps the Spanish one as well. If some native speaker of these languages disagrees, please feel free to comment the answer. I'm fairly sure I translated well, but if there is some mistake, it would be good to know.</sup>

Comment: So @Alenanno, what those sentences mean? The sentences you wrote as examples of other structures of asking someone's name. Please provide exact literal meaning (not conceptual meaning). :)

Comment: @Saeed Neamati: Sure!

Comment: @Evpok: Thanks for the corrections! :)

Comment: @Raphink: thanks to you too eheh

Comment: Well, Italian, Spanish and French are related and share the same structure. Swedish, German and English are related and share the same structure (except that English uses *What* instead of *Why*, but a few German people tend to use *What*, too). I've got the feeling that there's indeed a historical reasoning.

Comment: C'est très vrai que plusieurs languages dérivés du latin utilise cette tournure. Je ne sais pas pourquoi c'est la réponse favorite. J'espère qu'il y aura une vraie réponse à cette question. Je ne dis pas que ce post est inutile, mais ce n'est tout de même pas une réponse.

Answer (score 12):

In Russian we say “Как вас зовут?”, literally “How do (they) call you?”. English “What is your name?” feels a bit too formal. I mean, what is it, an interrogation? :-) One needs to learn that this is a natural way to ask this question in English. And you feel it is only because you are a native English speaker (well, I guess you are).

Just think of another question: “How old are you?”. And then think of “What is your age?”. Which one sounds more natural? I think, the first one is, to you. So that must give you an idea of how “Quel est votre nom ?” might sound to a Frenchman (which I am not, so it’s just a guess).

Languages are not translations of each other. There are different traditions as to how to express yourself, and there’s are many phrases in French which sound even more strange to us (just think of “*être en train de faire quelque chose*” or “*il fait beau*”).

Comment: In French, you would ask _Quel âge avez-vous ?_ which is way closer to _what is your age_. Noone would ever ask _Comment es-tu vieux ?_ So yes, as you say, languages are not translations of each other.

Comment: ça ne répond pas non plus à la question, bien que ce soit intéressant. Car le "comment ils t'appellent" est logique, mais pas le comment tu t'appelles toi-même.

Answer (score 7):

*"Comment vous appelez-vous"* doesn't really mean "how do you call yourself"; rather, *s'appeler* would roughly mean "be named". So the translation would be "What are you named?". *"Je m'appelle Alain"* means "I am called Alain" rather than "I call myself Alain".

That said, *"Quel est votre nom?"* isn't incorrect; I would even say it's rather widely used, for example in administrations.

Comment: *Comment vous-appellez-vous* **does** mean "how do you call yourself". "How are you named" would be *Comment êtes-vous appellé?* or *Comment vous appelle-t-on?*, which is actually used in some contexts.

Comment: Plus you're not answering the question.

Comment: @Joubarc, even with your explanation, `what are you called` or `what are you named` are still strange. I mean, a name is `something` that belongs to somebody. Semantically and philosophically, we can ask `where is your name`? But what people ask about, is the name itself. Thus they ask `what is your name`, and since a name never gets lost, they don't ask `where is your name`. I reckon there must be a different historical background behind this. :)

Comment: Can't argue the "not answering the question part" - that's quite true, and I should have left my remark as comment instead.

Comment: I do maintain however that _"s'appeler"_ is **not** translated by "to call oneself". _"s'appeler"_ is a pronominal verb which is different from _"appeler"_. Similarly, if I say _"Je m'ennuie."_, it doesn't mean that I am annoying myself. Or _"Le fromage se mange avec du pain"_ doesn't mean "The cheese eats itself with bread". The dictionnary I have (an admitedly old Harrap's) here gives _"s'appeler"_ = "_(avoir pour nom)_ to be called", _"s'ennuyer"_ = "to be/get bored" _"se manger"_ = "to be eaten". I'm curious as to what yours says.

Comment: *Comment nous appellez-vous?* would mean *How do you call us?*. If you think so, how would you say *How do you call yourself?* in French? Fact is *Comment vous appellez-vous?* is ambiguous and could mean both.

Comment: @Joubarc, I'm not a French speaker (francophone), but I can read and understand French. "Tais-toi!" seems to me (I'm talking about unconscious understanding after 2 years of reading) like "make yourself silent" instead of "be quite".

Comment: @Saeed: I think you meant "Be quiet". :D

Comment: C'est malin, l'idée du fromage qui se mange lui-même va me hanter toute la nuit maintenant.

Comment: Pardon, je downvote, parce que je ne suis pas du tout d'accord avec l'explication, et cela ne donne pas de source. Cela donne uniquement une opinion, un sentiment.

Comment: ""I am called Alain" rather than "I call myself Alain". C'est une interprétation personnelle qui fait fi du réflexif. Ce n'est pas "ils m'appellent", mais "je m'appelle moi-même", étymologiquement = c'est le sens de la question. Bien sûr que le sens est "ils m'appellent", mais ça ne répond pas du coup.

Comment: Quote "I do maintain however that "s'appeler" is not translated by "to call oneself". "s'appeler" is a pronominal verb which is different from "appeler". Similarly, if I say "Je m'ennuie.", it doesn't mean that I am annoying myself" -> It's your own opinion, it's not the opinion of the dictionaries and etymological dictionaries. S'ennuyer doesn't mean "I'm boring myself", but I get bored by myself (= alone, not bothered by something else), ennuyer doesn't mean only to be bored, by bothered, so you missed the point.

Answer (score 1):

Dans l’Hexagone, *Nom*, *prénom*, *date et lieu de naissance* et *adresse* sont les requêtes faites par la police et l'administration pour identifier quelqu'un, c'est une requête intrusive d'identification à des fins réglementaires, de sécurité et de contrôle.

En écho, *quel est votre nom* induit inconsciemment une attitude de défense de la personne interpellée (dans le sens à qui l'on s'adresse), elle se demande : qu'est-ce qu'il va en faire, encore un démarcheur, qu'est-ce que cela peut lui faire…

> *Appeler* : inviter (qqn) à venir en prononçant son nom, par un mot, un cri, un bruit. (*Le petit Robert*)

*Comment vous appelez-vous*, devient ainsi une demande de convention formelle pour une relation consentie, beaucoup plus amicale. Dans ce cas, on ne peut refuser de présenter le nom social usuel : « On m'appelle Dédé », sans qu'il y ait plus d'engagement, l'interpellant pourra demander aux alentours « Vous avez vu Dédé aujourd'hui ? » et parler de la personne que tout le monde connait.

Bien sûr tout ceci est subjectif, et dépend de l'intonation et de la situation. Je ne serais pas choqué qu'une personne anglophone me demande mon nom, mais qu'en réunion ou en public on m'interpelle en me le demandant, me mettra sur la défensive, je préférerais un « S'il vous plaît, comment doit-on vous appeler ? »

*Comment dois-je vous appeler*, si la situation est formelle, sinon dans une conversation amicale, l'un et l'autre se disent.

---

Si l'on est obligé de demander le nom de la personne à qui l'on s'adresse, on peut toujours s'en sortir en affirmant :

> Nous n'avons pas été présentés, comment vous appelez-vous ?
>   Je n'ai pas retenu votre nom lors des présentations, comment dois-je vous appeler ?

Comment: J'aime bien l'explication par l'inquisition, mais c'est vraiment très formel, tout ça. « Comment doit-je vous appeler » ne demande même pas le nom, en fin de compte, par exemple. Dans une conversation amicale, je répondrai *Maître* par retour de moquerie ; je n'envisage pas être demandé ça sérieusement avec cette formulation.

Comment: Indépendament, « se disent » d'après moi, et certains retours à la ligne sont vraiment très agressifs (après *me demande mon nom*, *really* ?). [Pense aux animaux mignons !](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/312/documents-et-institutions-de-reference-de-la-langue#comment535_312)

Comment: .. et je répondrai, tout aussi amicalement : "Mettons un thermomètre" [mettre un terme au 'Maître', ou arrêter d'utiliser cette formule]. - C'est pourquoi, devant quelqu'un qui vous intimide, qui est socialement importante pour vous, il m'est arrivé de choisir cette expression, et parfois, le sourire amusé de cette dernière a fait fondre la glace plus vite que prévu, j'ai souvent obtenu le surnom familier sans connaître le nom officiel. C'est encore une fois une question de situation, d'intonation, d'ouverture d'esprit, de sourire.

Comment: Ah ! admirable. À ce moment là, je rajouterais à la réponse que ça inclus une bonne dose de déférence, ce qui est loin d'être évident, en l'état.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks C'est un retour d'opposition de situation : dans un cas cela ne pose pas de problème, la ligne suivante, toujours dans le même contexte, il peut y avoir de l'agressivité, de *l'inquisition* comme vous l'avez si justement souligné.

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a que dans certaines compagnies aériennes (dont Air France hélàs) que le commandant de bord se présente ainsi: "mon nom est Gérard Lambert". Traduction mot à mot de "my name is". La seule formule correcte est : Je m'appelle (ou à la limite "Je suis") Gérard Lambert". Donc: en français on doit dire: "Comment vous appelez-vous?", "Comment t'appelles-tu?".