# Why "qu'est-ce que c'est", why not only "qu'est-ce"?

Tags: expressions, questions

I'm learning French through reading and still I sometimes encounter some phrases which are not intuitive for me. One of'em is asked in [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/330/pourquoi-comment-vous-appelez-vous-et-pas-quel-est-votre-nom-comme-en-an). Another is the current question you're reading.

A well-known French phrase is **qu'est-ce que c'est**. This phrase is used when you want to ask **what's going on**. However, in my mind this literally means **What is it that it is?**. This sounds very odd to me. If we want to simply ask **What is it?**, what should we ask? Is **qu'est-ce?** a common phrase? I ask this because I haven't seen it anywhere. What other alternatives do we have for this purpose?

Comment: **Qu'est-ce?** is common but a little bit old or reserved for literature. But it can be found in a common language. Can the "French linguistic experts" (You all know who that means, I'm sure) check if **qu'est-ce que c'est?** is a redundent expression exactly like **au jour d'aujourd'hui**?

Comment: I think "qu'est-ce" isn't widely used in speech simply because it can be misunderstood for "caisse".

Comment: @Saeed Neamati It is exactly that, **What is it that it is?**, however, fortunately, as is the case for many such things in many languages, you, indigenous speaker, don't learn them by means of logical thinking, but through sheer rote until the day, if you're lucky enough to reflect a bit about language you realise that it is complete nonsense and that there is nothing to do about that except using them or shutting up.

Answer (score 18):

First, “what's going on” will usually be translated by “qu'est-ce qu'il se passe”, sometimes “qu'est-ce qu'il y a” when anticipating a problem. It can also be translated as “qu'est-ce que c'est” but only in specific cases, for example, when you just heard some strange noise.

The phrase “qu'est-ce que c'est” is indeed strange, but very common and standard. I would say that the reason is that in spoken French subject–verb inversions tend to be very rare (unless you don't care about being perceived as pedant). People usually ask questions using “est-ce” as the only subject–verb inversion:

> Qu'est-ce qu'il y a ?
> Quand est-ce qu'il vient ?

Instead of:

> Qu'y a-t-il ?
> Quand vient-il ?

And “Qu'est-ce ?” is also being replaced by “Qu'est-ce que c'est ?” through this mapping. The former is perfectly correct, but seldom found, even in written French.

---

In fact, in informal speech, French bypasses those inversions completely… (and strictly speaking this gives rise to non-grammatical sentences):

> Il part quand ? Quand c'est qu'il part ?
> C'est quand qu'il part ?
>
> Il va où? Où il va ?
> Où c'est qu'il va ?
> C'est où qu'il va ?
>
> Qui c'est qui s'en va ?
> C'est qui qui s'en va ?
>
> C'est quoi ?

Answer (score 6):

*Qu'est-ce que c'est ?* veut dire  *What is it ?* (et pas *What's going on* ?)

Il y a plusieurs façons de poser une question :

1- **L'inversion du sujet :**

- Viens-tu ?
- Que fait-il ?
- Est-ce vrai ?

L'emploi de l'**inversion du sujet** est du style soutenu.

2- **Est-ce que** :

- Est-ce que tu viens ?
- Qu'est-ce qu'il fait ?
- Est-ce que c'est vrai ?

N'essaie pas de décortiquer l'expression, mais considère juste que c'est une expression, un gadget (donc quelque chose de pas forcément utile ou indispensable) qui permet de poser une question.

L'emploi de **est-ce que** est d'usage courant, considéré par certains (pas par tous) comme familier.

3- Garder l'**ordre des mots de la phrase affirmative** et marquer l'interrogation :

- à l'écrit : par la présence du point d'interrogation,
- à l'oral : en modifiant l'intonation.

Tu viens ? (Le ton de *viens* étant plus haut que celui de *tu* quand on dit la phrase)

Tu comprendras mieux en écoutant les phrases proposées sur [cette page](http://www.frenchtutorial.com/standard/interrogative/convert.php) que j'ai trouvée  en cherchant sur le [Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/), où tu trouveras beaucoup d'[autres exercices sur l'interrogation](http://www.lepointdufle.net/interrogation.htm) en français.

Donc tu peux très bien dire *Qu'est-ce ?* pour demander *What is it ?*, c'est tout à fait correct.  Mais personnellement je ne le dis pas tous les jours sauf si je veux faire un effet particulier. Dans la vie de tous les jours je dis *Qu'est-ce que c'est* ?

Answer (score 4):

Both *qu'est-ce ?* and *qu'est-ce que c'est ?* are correct. Even if it seems to me that the first one is less common (especially in spoken French).  There are contexts where the second form is mandatory. Compare:

> Qui te fait dire cela ?
>   Qui est-ce qui te fait dire cela ?

With

> *Quoi te fait dire cela ?
>   Qu'est-ce qui te fait dire cela ?

So I wouldn't be surprised if teachers present  the second form before going into the details about when the first can be and can't be used.

Answer (score 4):

In French, according to the "Bescherelle - La Grammaire", printed 1997, the following are considered as **pronom interrogatifs complexes**:

For people:

- qui est-ce qui
- qui est-ce que
- à, de qui est-ce que
- préposition + qui est-ce que

For objects:

- qu'est-ce qui
- qu'est-ce que
- à, de quoi est-ce que
- préposition + quoi est-ce que

The rule is the following:

When the question is about people, one should use "qui est-ce ...". When the question is about objects, one should use "qu'est-ce ..." as it is the equivalent of "quoi est-ce..." .

For example, the two following sentence have the same meaning:

- Qui est passé?
- Qui est-ce qui est passé?

Answer (score 3):

Je traduirais *qu'est-ce que c'est ?* par *what is this?*.
Je préfère *qu'est ce (donc) que ceci/cela ?* à *qu'est ce ?*, qui impliquent que l'on pointe l’objet en question. Toutes deux étant d'un registre soutenu on préférera *qu'est-ce que c'est* si l'on ne veut pas être pédantique.

En général on dira plutot "Qu'est-ce que c'est que ceci/cela/ce truc… ?".
Pour ce qui est de "What's going on?" on peut le traduire par "Que se passe-t-il ?".

L'autre sens de *Qu'est-ce que c'est ?* sera mieux véhiculé par un *Qu'y a-t-il ?* voire un *Qui est là ?*, car la première demande une intonation particulière pour être comprise et est donc à proscrire pour éviter toute confusion. Il en existe 2 usages principaux: lorsque qu'il y a quelqu'un à la porte et si un aristocrate demande à son domestique qui-va-là de manière hautaine et l'air dérangé.

Answer (score 2):

"Qu'est-ce" can not be understood as "caisse", because it will be always "la/une/sa/ta... caisse".

You shoud do always the inversion subject-verb in a question, but it is nowadays almost forgotten in speaking (more commmon in writing)

Redundant phrases are worth it only if you can pronounce fast. It is not artistic French so don't lose time and get to the end.

For beginners, even if it is not the top of the art, much easier is to say :
"c'est quoi?"
"il fait quoi?"

For graduates, you can try with:
"qu'est-ce que c'est que ça ?" = "qu'est-ce ?" with some surprise/irritation.
Pronounce "kèskessèksa" where è can be é (as always with ai/et/es)

Yes, redundancy is a way to be well understood.

Comment: We also use redundancy with the short word "où" (Where). To be well understood, we often say "Où ça?" instead of "Où?" alone.  Shorter is not alway better!