# Répéter « que », « ce » et « est » dans une question, pourquoi?

Tags: sens, usage, questions

J'ai vu plusieurs formes de questions, mais les deux qui m'étonnent le plus sont :

- Qu'est-ce que ce drôle de bruit ?
- Qu'est-ce que c'est que ce drôle de bruit ?

Le deux sont correctes, je crois bien, mais je suis certain qu'il y  a une différence entre les deux. Je crois que c'est une différence de force, mais je souhaiterais l'avis de quelqu'un s'y connait mieux que moi.

Quelle est cette différence ?

Comment: There is information here : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1412/17649

Comment: Note that both the "que" is not repeated because of the question but because this particle links two equivalent noun phrases: « C'est une bête terrifiante **que** le lion »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La différence principale concerne le registre.

La première phrase est de registre plus soutenu. Elle a peu de chance d'être rencontrée à l'oral.

La deuxième est de registre courant.

Une version plus familière et celle qui serait probablement la plus utilisée dans une conversation de tous les jours est :

> C'est quoi, ce drôle de bruit ?

Comment: Intéressant. J'ai vu la première dans certaines emmissions et il m'a semblé que l'utilisation était dans des moments d'émotion forte. Merci. Je n'ai pas l'attendu, ça !

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de répétition à proprement parler, il s'agit de la même phrase avec deux mots interrogatifs différents (le premier qui oblige l'inversion, le deuxième qui l'empêche)

> Qu'est-ce que ce drôle de bruit?

Le mot interrogatif est *que*, suivi du verbe avec pronom enclitique *est-ce*.

> Qu'est-ce que c'est que ce drôle de bruit?

Le mot interrogatif est *qu'est-ce que*, suivi du verbe avec pronom proclitique *c'est*.