# Agreement of the past participle in presence of a reflexive pronoun

Tags: pronoms, verbes, conjugaison, pronoms-réfléchis

> Les reines se sont succédé(?)

Is there any clear reason to explain that *succéder* is invariable in this case? Is there any French conjugation rule I missed, or is it relative to the verb *succéder* which is a bit special?

As far as I know, I would write something like *les feuilles se sont envolées*, so what is basically the difference?

Comment: `[citation needed]` ;·)

Comment: Yes, I too think NNzz is giving too much credit to something that's merely a typo.

Comment: Actually, googling suggests it **is** invariable, only it shouldn't have the feminine form to begin with.

Comment: Ma question peut vous aider : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/pas-daccord-pour-se-rendre-compte-de-et-se-plaire-complaire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Si on n'utilise pas de pronom, cette phrase peut aussi être écrite :

> Les reines ont succédé aux reines.

On s’aperçoit que le rôle du pronom réfléchi est celui d'un objet indirect (COI) dans cette phrase. Il apparait aussi que le véritable auxiliaire est *avoir*, et qu'il ne peut y avoir d'accord puisqu'il n'y a pas d’objet direct.

Dans une phrase qui utilise un pronom réfléchi, l'auxiliaire *avoir* est remplacé par l'auxiliaire *être*, mais l'accord n'est pas modifié. Donc :

> Les reines se sont succédé.

À proprement parler, le verbe *se succéder* n'existe pas, sauf pour cet emploi *accidentellement pronominal* (succéder les uns aux autres). En vérité, le verbe est ici *succéder*. C'est différent de *s'envoler* qui est un verbe *essentiellement pronominal*. Il n'est pas possible d'écrire « les feuilles se sont envolées » d'une façon différente, *envoler* n'existe pas.

---

Autres exemples d'emplois accidentellement pronominaux :

> Ils se sont parlé.

Il n'y a pas d'accord pour la même raison : les uns parlent *aux* autres.

> Ils se sont regardés.

Dans ce cas, le pronom est objet direct (les uns regardent *les* autres), et il est placé avant le verbe, d'où l'accord.

Comment: Note: Most of the time, when the auxiliary is *être* the agreement is done either with the subject or with the reflexive pronoun used as direct object (when there is one). Cases where the reflexive pronoun is an indirect object are seldom found, so this agreement looks strange and quite uncomfortable, even to a native speaker.

Comment: Certains verbes ont un sens différent quand ils sont employés de manière essentiellement pronominale, ce qui peut générer des ambigüités avec un éventuel emploi accidentellement pronominal (c'est la raison pour laquelle certains déconseillent _je m'excuse_, et on a déjà traité de [s'appeler](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/333/176)).

Answer (score 1):

The [Wiktionnary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/succ%C3%A9d%C3%A9es) has [interesting insights](http://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discussion%3asucc%C3%A9d%C3%A9es) on that matter.

<sub><sub>My previous answer was wrong, fooled by the feminine, and a better one will come later.</sub></sub>

Comment: "Les rois se sont succédé" was a part of a "Dictée de Pivot" as far as I can remember. Maybe this link gives information, but I don't understand what's being said on it... http://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discussion:succédées

Comment: I corrected, I meant "Les reines se sont succédé". My mistake.

Comment: @NNzz: Ah, now it gets interesting :)