# Past participles of reflexive verbs

Tags: participe-passé

Is it correct to say "Ils se sont parlé" for "They spoke to each other? Should the past participle agree with the subject? "Ils se sont parlés."

Comment: Also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/agreement-of-the-past-participle-in-presence-of-a-reflexive-pronoun/4443#4443

Comment: Welcome to French SE! Don't mind the close, we just don't keep many questions on the same topic here.