# Why the pronunciation of "Monsieur" as "Missieur"?

Tags: prononciation, société, voyelles, évolution

The French word *Monsieur* meaning Mister,  looks like it should be pronounced `MON-sieur`, giving effect to the *O* and *N*. But I hear it pronounced more like `MISS-sieur`. Why is that? Is it that I am hearing it wrong?

There is another similar French word, which is *Monseigneur*. Is it also pronounced `MIS-seigneur`, or in the more “obvious” fashion, `MON-seigneur`? If the latter, why the difference?

Comment: Monseigneur is pronounced as it's written. Where did you hear *Monsieur* pronounced as if it had an *i* ? (I pronounce it as *Meussieu*, and I don't know about IPA.)

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas: I said that Monsieur was pronounced MORE LIKE [emphasis added] "Miss-sieur" (to my ear). That does not rule out your more correct transliteration, "Meussieu."

Comment: You could easily have [checked the actual pronunciation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monsieur). Originally (old French) written in two words (mon+sieur) and pronounced  /mɔ̃sjœʁ/ it started to be written in one word as pronunciation evolved. Evolution of pronunciation of vowel sounds is a feature in most languages (I say most as I am not enough of a linguist to generalise). At one time it was pronounced /mu'sjø/ or /mo'sjø/ but it was never pronounced with an /i/ sound. Monseigneur is only used nowadays for clerics, it used to be used for royals, but we don't have them any more in France.

Comment: @Laure: While not exactly France, there is still the Prince of Monaco called "Monseigneur".

Comment: @TomAu:  As to the pronunciation of *Monseigneur* you could also have [easily checked](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monseigneur).

Comment: It's just like how "Milord" in English is pronounced differently from "my Lord."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question of the actual pronunciation of both *monsieur* and *monseigneur* need not be asked, but I will try and answer the other part of the question, i.e. why is the combination of the letters (o+n) pronounced differently in each word.

I'll start by quoting David Crystal "Languages are always in a state of flux... the most noticeable and frequent changes affect pronunciation and vocabulary...".

Vowel sounds are more prone to evolution than consonants. I suppose it is because phonatory organs are not as easily controlled when sounding vowels than when sounding consonants (just a hint, but the question could be asked on [linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com)<sup>1</sup>.
Another factor in pronunciation evolution is the question of the stressed syllables. Vowels will change more easily when unstressed.

Now, back to *monsieur* and *monseigneur*.  Both are a combination of the possessive **mon** + sieur or seigneur, and both were written as two separate words that concatenated as the French language evolved.
When said as two separate words (mon+sieur), had two equally stressed syllables. But as the words evolved into one single entity with a shift in meaning and the loss of the understanding of the original meaning (including the fact that *mon* was no longer perceived as a possessive)  the first syllable became unstressed (French words are regularly stressed on the last syllable), the nasal /ɔ̃/ evolved into the unstressed vowel sound /ə/.
In *monseigneur*, even when concatenated into one single word the *mon* has always retained its possessive meaning (I suppose we could say that French people still perceive the word *monseigneur*  as the English perceive *my lord*), and even nowadays when we say the word we tend to have an auxiliary stress on the first syllable, thus the original  /ɔ̃/ sound remaining unchanged.

For more on the evolution of vowel pronunciation in the French language one could have a look at the wikipedia article on [Old French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancien_fran%C3%A7ais#Syst.C3.A8me_vocalique) and at this book:  [Introduction à la phonétique historique du français](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_%C3%A0_la_phon%C3%A9tique_historiqu.html?id=GB1VxSeE1r4C&redir_esc=y) 
by Annick Englebert for a study of the historical evolution of French pronunciation.

----EDIT----
<sup>1</sup>  I asked the question on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/is-there-a-biological-reason-to-vowel-shift) and got very interesting answers.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/859/, et [cette remarque](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/312/documents-et-institutions-de-reference-de-la-langue#comment535_312) aussi.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas - un petit cadeau pour dénouer la tension: )

Comment: Une réponse excellente, plus axée sur le *pourquoi* que nos autres contributions. (+1)

Comment: Just another idea, while it is only intuition without the least bit of proof behind: maybe _monseigneur_ preserved its original pronunciation because it is much less used than _monsieur_. Anyway, great answer.

Answer (score 6):

The pronunciation of the word is indeed the irregular `[məsjø]`, not naively `[mɔ̃sjœr]` (though historically it seems to have been the very first way of saying it, then `[mɔsjø]`, then the modern one). I never heard the `[misjø]` you're referring to.

*Monseigneur* is pronounced regularly, like the words that compose the expression *Mon seigneur* (so : `[mɔ̃sɛɲœr]`).

About the reason that could explain this odd pronunciation, there's a few explanations [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/monsieur), [there](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monsieur) and even [there](https://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3746), but I guess it's not very satisfying or definitive. Anyway, euphony is probably one of the reasons it changed, because the term is one of the most heavily-employed of the language, considering the *modern* pronunciation is slightly quicker.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe are you speaking about *messieurs*, it's the plural of *monsieur*, or developed, this could come from *mes seigneurs* → *mes sieurs*.

This could be pronounced like `mae see eu` (not `me` but `mae`), unfortunately `eu` does not have an equivalent in English.

Or maybe you are hearing some joke, as some aim to represent the outlander spoken French of a

- South African:  *missié*, spoken like `miss yeah`
- North African: *missiou*, spoken like `miss you`
- Chinese: *missie*, spoken like `me sea`
- …

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you going.

Comment: Merci, je découvre ce cite et vraiment, je ris Gaulle! A little less funny in english, at all ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so to give an actual simple answer to this question, it just seems to be an incorrect pronunciation that's become popularized in urban culture. More accurately, what it could be is people taking the plural word messieurs and thinking that the singular form of that would be messieur instead of monsieur. Either way it's wrong but that's where I believe it comes from.

Comment: You write, "what it could be is people taking the plural word messieurs and thinking ..." Is this just speculation on your part or do you have any data to back up this claim?

Answer (score -2):

I think it's pronounced /məsjø/ because that is easier than /mɔ̃.sjø/.

Answer (score -3):

1. You need to say **mon** like when you say in french *me*

   *for exemple:* “*je **me** suis fait mal*”
2. Then **sieur** like when you say in french *si* and *yeux*

   *for exemple:* “***Si** tu viens, je viens*” and “*tu as de beaux **yeux***”

   **ME-SI-YEUX** → Monsieur

Comment: I think "how is it pronounced?" was already answered many times, while not even being the question.